# Store a class method in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am developing an app with Django framework and in a part of it I receive a class instance that contains data. Now I want to store this data in my database, what should I do?

For example if *incoming* is this:

```
>>>type(incoming)
<class 'foo.bar.model'>
>>>incoming.name
'hosein'
```

And the class attributes are: *name, age, gender, phone_no ,...*

Now I want to store all this attributes values in my app's model called *app_name.models.Profile*

I know that I can define a model like this:

***models.py***

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    # And so on ...
```

But this is not my answer, I'm searching for permanent and exact way except define and storing fields one by one.
Is there any way to define some dynamic model fields for my model class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call each class method on `incoming` objects to get results, then use the corresponding field name to store in a `Profile` instance. Here's a rough example, you might need to tweak it a little to make it work for you:

```
# create a Profile object
new_profile = Profile()

for name in dir(incoming):
    # loop on each method for incoming object
    attribute = getattr(incoming, name)
    if not ismethod(attribute):
        # get the value of the attribute
        value = attribute
    setattr(new_profile, name, value)

new_profile.save()
```

python doc about [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: I assume that you where talking about class methods, but `incoming.name` sounds like class attributes not methods, or are they class methods with `@property` decorator?

Comment: You are right I mixed up method and attributes in asking question :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but one another !
What is `ismethod()` ?

Comment: Google is your friend for unknown knowledge. `ismethod()` is to check whether if it's a method object or not(the name says itself). But sounds like you want attributes, so I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok I get it, it needs `from inspect import ismethod`, thank for you answer again :)